# Build flex library using mxmlc

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I want to build a flex library project directly through the mxmlc compiler. My library has one .as file and it is under a package call com.test

```
package com.test { public class Main {  public function Main(){...
```

I run the following command on the cmd

```
D:\4.11.0\bin\mxmlc D:\TestLibrary\src\com\test\Main.as
```

But it gives me the following error

```
Error: A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', as the definition's package, 'com.test'
```

If I remove the package definition from the script as follows, it works.

```
package { public class Main { ...
```

My question is why this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to additionally tell the compiler the root of your sources:

```
mxmlc D:\TestLibrary\src\com\test\Main.as -source-path D:\TestLibrary\src\
```

by providing the "source-path" property you are telling the compiler where the root is and releative from that it now should know that com.test.Main is the relative path to your class.

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I want to build a swc of the library project, but this command makes a swf file. How can I make a swc file?

Comment: Well mxmlc is for compiling swfs, if you want to compile a swc, use compc instead (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ad5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Charisofer, Finally I could build the library project and make the swc file. This is the command I used. Hope it will help for others.

```
D:\4.11.0\bin\compc -source-path D:\TestLibrary\src -include-sources D:\TestLibrary\src\com\test\Main.as -debug=false -output D:\Auto_Release\main.swc
```

To build swf, need to use mxmlc

To build swc need to use compc